# mysql_connect() текст ошибки в нормальной кодировке

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется файл с подключением к mysql в кодировке utf-8 без BOM:

```
$connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die('Нет подключения к базе данных');
mysql_select_db ($cdb, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
```

Но при отсутствии подключения к серверу я получаю ошибку в неправильной кодировке:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): ������ ��������� ���������� ��� ����������, �.�. �� ������� �������� �� ��������� ���� �� ������ ����� ������, ��� ��� ��������� ��� ������������� ���������� ��-�� ��������� ������� ��� ����������� ��������. in ...
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить ошибку в нормальной кодировке?

Comment: MySQL-то тут каким боком? Это PHP "виноват" - его сообщение...

Comment: я понимаю, стандартная кодировка у php utf-8

Comment: Не заниматься разработкой под виндоус.

Comment: и в качестве отдельного совета рекомендую почитать, что написано по ссылке php.net/mysql_connect

Comment: и потом поинтересоваться, как давно написан туториал, по которому вы учитесь

Comment: У меня просто нет желания переписывать всё под mysqli и pdo, когда под mysql и так отлично работает

Answer (score 0):

Может быть в файле .htaccess добавить AddDefaultCharset utf-8?

Comment: Это не даст эффекта, проверено

Comment: Нужно копать в сторону вывода ошибок mysql на стороне пхп